# How do chained assignments work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A quote from something:

```
>>> x = y = somefunction()
```

is the same as

```
>>> y = somefunction()
>>> x = y
```

Question: Is

```
x = y = somefunction()
```

the same as

```
x = somefunction()
y = somefunction()
```

?

Based on my understanding, they should be same because `somefunction` can only return exactly one value.

Comment: You might want to use the `python` tag instead of `python-3.x` since it's more widely followed and your question isn't specific to Python 3. You also don't need to reiterate the tag in the title, but it is good to mention your version of Python somewhere.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

They will not necessarily work the same if `somefunction` returns a mutable value. Consider:

```
>>> def somefunction():
...     return []
... 
>>> x = y = somefunction()
>>> x.append(4)
>>> x
[4]
>>> y
[4]
>>> x = somefunction(); y = somefunction()
>>> x.append(3)
>>> x
[3]
>>> y
[]
```

Comment: Good catch. And even if it's an immutable value, `x is y` will be different (save nasty pitfalls like the caching of string literals and small integers).

Comment: Yes, great point.  I have gotten in trouble more than once when I want to be lazy and do `x = y = []`.  If `x` and `y` are supposed to be different lists, then this is bugs ahoy.

Comment: I think x=y=somefunction works by first assign value to y and then assign x as a pointer to y

Comment: @JiapengZhang That's not quite true. Both `x` and `y` will both be referencing the same underlying object, but not each other. Consider `x=y=[]; y=3; print(x)`. It will print `[]`, not `3` because there is no connection between the names `x` and `y`, just the underlying values.

Answer (score 95):

### Left first

```
x = y = some_function()
```

is equivalent to

```
temp = some_function()
x = temp
y = temp
```

Note the order. **The leftmost target is assigned first**.  (A similar expression in C [may](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19356014/673991) assign in the [opposite order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24641021/673991).) From the docs on [Python assignment](https://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> ...assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

Disassembly shows this:

```
>>> def chained_assignment():
...     x = y = some_function()
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(chained_assignment)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (some_function)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 DUP_TOP
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

CAUTION: the [same object](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html) is always assigned to each target.  So as @Wilduck and @andronikus point out, you probably never want this:

```
x = y = []   # Wrong.
```

In the above case x and y refer to the same list. Because lists are [mutable](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Mutable_vs_Immutable_Objects), appending to x would [seem to affect](http://bjc.berkeley.edu/bjc-r/cur/programming/python/list_mutability.html) y.

```
x = []   # Right.
y = []
```

Now you have two names referring to two distinct empty lists.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit? You said: "The same, identical value is always assigned to each target (when chained assignment)", so it is reasonable to think that when i do `x = y = []` - i get `temp = []` `x = temp`, `y = temp`. But then you said :  "you probably never want to do this: `x = y = []` Because then x and y are the same object." - and I really get two variable, pointing at the same object, not two variable, pointing at two different empty lists.

Comment: @jumpjet67 Better?

Comment: There is no limit to perfection ;-). Good and well explained answer actually.

Comment: @jumpjet67 Spoken like a true, unrepentant (Безнаказанный?) perfectionist. Thank you sir.

Comment: Your answer became better a bit, so as I wished - if I understood your comment correctly. My English isn't good enough to understand such words as "unrepentant" completely true. Is it about 'not feeling shame or regret about one's actions or attitudes.'?

Comment: My apologies if this is the case.

Comment: No apologies necessary, friend @jumpjet67. I just meant to appreciate your statement, there is no limit to perfection. No shame aiming for that. Can you suggest any further improvements to this posting?

Comment: The different order is totally important! Thanks!

Comment: This answered my question with the `temp` variable. I was wondering if the middle variable in the chain was an attribute or something else would need to be looked up.

Comment: Good explanation.  I find this behavior unintuitive, and was burned by it.  I had `x = x.a = y`, expecting it to behave as `x.a = y; x = y`, but because of the assignment order, it effectively did `x = y; x.a = y` which failed rather horribly.  I suppose I could do `x.a = x = y` to get the desired behavior, but this seems really misleading to me.

Comment: @TomKarzes great example of a chained assignment burn. Sounds like a linked-list nightmare.

Comment: But this is pretty nice when you want to rename a variable but you don't want the old contents to stick around in memory, right? `x_list = [...]; x_list = fn_a(x_list); x_list = fn_b(x_list); x_array = x_list = np.fn(x_list)`. Only the array exists but we got x_list out of the memory without having to wait for `del x_list`.

Comment: @grofte Not sure I'm getting your example after several rereads. But I would suggest that **tricky brevity is NOT nice**. Code should be human readable. Side effects should be recast into obvious, explicit consequences. Your future brain is a tender thing.

Comment: `turtle = turtle['standing-on'] = {}`  In other words, "it's turtles all the way down!"

Comment: @AJNeufeld now that's just mean['mean']['mean']... 

Comment: There's no reason to bring a temp variable into it. `x = y = somefunction()` is equivalent to `y = somefunction()` and then `x = y`. That's literally what's happening.

Comment: @kindall no. `x` is assigned first.

Answer (score 16):

What if `somefunction()` returns different values each time it is called?

```
import random

x = random.random()
y = random.random()
```

Comment: That's a valid alternative counterexample although I didn't make such an assumption in the OP.

Comment: The point is that you'd have to make the reverse assumption, that the function always returns the same thing, for what you said to hold.

Answer (score 9):

### It would result in the same *only* if the function has no side-effects and returns a singleton in a deterministic manner (given its inputs).

E.g.:

```
def is_computer_on():
    return True

x = y = is_computer_on()
```

or

```
def get_that_constant():
    return some_immutable_global_constant
```

Note that the result would be the same, but the process to achieve the result would not:

```
def slow_is_computer_on():
    sleep(10)
    return True
```

The content of x and y variables would be the same, but the instruction `x = y = slow_is_computer_on()` would last 10 seconds, and its counterpart `x = slow_is_computer_on() ; y = slow_is_computer_on()` would last 20 seconds.

### It would be *almost* the same if the function has no side-effects and returns an immutable in a deterministic manner (given its inputs).

E.g.:

```
def count_three(i):
    return (i+1, i+2, i+3)

x = y = count_three(42)
```

Note that the same catches explained in previous section applies.

Why I say *almost*? Because of this:

```
x = y = count_three(42)
x is y  # <- is True

x = count_three(42)
y = count_three(42)
x is y  # <- is False
```

Ok, using `is` is something strange, but this illustrates that the return is not the same. This is important for the mutable case:

### It is dangerous and may lead to bugs if the function returns a mutable

This has also been answered in this question. For the sake of completeness, I replay the argument:

```
def mutable_count_three(i):
    return [i+1, i+2, i+3]

x = y = mutable_count_three(i)
```

Because in that scenario `x` and `y` are the same object, doing an operation like `x.append(42)` whould mean that both `x` and `y` hold a reference to a list which now has 4 elements.

### It would not be the same if the function has side-effects

Considering a print a side-effect (which I find valid, but other examples may be used instead):

```
def is_computer_on_with_side_effect():
    print "Hello world, I have been called!"
    return True

x = y = is_computer_on_with_side_effect()  # One print

# The following are *two* prints:
x = is_computer_on_with_side_effect()
y = is_computer_on_with_side_effect()
```

Instead of a print, it may be a more complex or more subtle side-effect, but the fact remains: the method is called once or twice and that may lead to different behaviour.

### It would not be the same if the function is non-deterministic given its inputs

Maybe a simple random method:

```
def throw_dice():
    # This is a 2d6 throw:
    return random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6)

x = y = throw_dice()  # x and y will have the same value

# The following may lead to different values:
x = throw_dice()
y = throw_dice()
```

But, things related to clock, global counters, system stuff, etc. is sensible to being non-deterministic given the input, and in those cases the value of `x` and `y` may diverge.

Answer (score 7):

As already stated by Bob Stein the order of assignment is important; look at the very interesting following case:

```
L = L[1] = [42, None]
```

Now, what does contain `L`? You must understand that a single object being initially `[42, None]` which is assigned to `L`; finally, something like `L[1] = L` is performed. You thus have some cyclic infinite "list" created (the word "list" being here more similar to some `CONS` in Lisp with a scalar `42` being the `CAR` and the list itself being the `CDR`).

Just type:

```
>>> L
[42, [...]]
```

then have some fun by typing `L[1]`, then `L[1][1]`, then `L[1][1][1]` until you reach the end...

#### Conclusion

This example is more complicated to understand than other ones in other answers, but on the other hand, you can see much quicker that

```
L = L[1] = [42, None]
```

is not the same as

```
L[1] = L = [42, None]
```

because the second one will raise an exception if `L` is not previously defined while the first one will always work.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
x = somefunction()
y = somefunction()
```

`somefunction` will be called twice instead of once.

Even if it returns the same result each time, this will be a noticeable if it takes a minute to return a result!
Or if it has a side effect e.g. asking the user for his password.