# What is this kind of assignment in Python called? a = b = True

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I know about [tuple unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) but what is this assignment called where you have multiple equals signs on a single line? a la `a = b = True`

It always trips me up a bit especially when the RHS is mutable, but I'm having real trouble finding the right keywords to search for in the docs.

Comment: I would call them "[chained](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Chained_assignment) [assignments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601823/how-do-chained-assignments-work)."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do chained assignments work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601823/how-do-chained-assignments-work)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's a chain of assignments and the term used to describe it is...

<sup>- Could I get a drumroll please?</sup>

#### *Chained Assignment*.

---

I just gave it a quite google run and found that there isn't that much to read on the topic, probably since most people find it very straight-forward to use (and only the true geeks would like to know more about the topic).

---

In the previous expression the order of evaluation can be viewed as starting at the right-most `=` and then working towards the left, which would be equivalent of writing:

```
b = True
a = b
```

---

The above order is what most language describe an *assignment-chain*, but python does it differently. In python the expression is evaluated as this below equivalent, though it won't result in any other result than what is previously described.

```
temporary_expr_result = True

a = temporary_expr_result
b = temporary_expr_result
```

---

Further reading available here on stackoverflow:

- **[How do chained assignments work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601823/how-do-chained-assignments-work)** [python](/questions/tagged/python)

Comment: It's calling this 'chained assignment' that is the real culprit. It'd be chained assignment if `a = b = c` meant that `b = c` is executed before `a = b`, but as you show that is not the case. Assignment takes place *sequentially* instead.

Comment: This clarifies that in situations where like `x = dictionary['x'] = value` the dictionary does not use set then get (like would be done if it expanded to `dictionary['x'] = value; x = dictionary['x']`) but instead only sets the dictionary value.

Answer (score 14):

@refp's answer is further supported with this output using the `dis` (disassembly) module:

```
>>> def a(x):
...   g = h = x
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 DUP_TOP
              4 STORE_FAST               1 (g)
              7 STORE_FAST               2 (h)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

The RHS is retrieved and duplicated, then stored into the destination variables left-to-right (try this yourself with `e = f = g = h = x`).

Some other posters have been confused if the RHS is a function call, like `a = b = fn()` - the RHS is only evaluated once, and then the result assigned to each successive variable. This may cause unwanted sharing if the returned value is a mutable, like a list or dict.

For those using `threading`, it is useful to note that there is no "atomicity" implied by the chained assignment form over multiple explicit assignment statements - a thread switch could occur between the assignments to g and h, and another thread looking at the two of them could see different values in the two variables.

From the [documentation, 7.2. Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), `g` and `h` being two *target lists*, `x` being the *expression list*:

> ```
> assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression)
> ```
>
> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns *the single resulting object* to each of the target lists, *from left to right*.

Comment: is there any documentation for this left-to-right evaluation available?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes, I've added the relevant excerpt from the documentation.

Answer (score 10):

OK, "chained assignment" was the search term I was after, but after a bit more digging I think it's not strictly correct. but it is easier to search for than "a special case of the assignment statement".

[The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29) [senderle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577088/senderle) linked to says:

> In Python, assignment statements are not expressions and thus do not
>   return a value. Instead, chained assignments are a series of
>   statements with multiple targets for a single expression. The
>   assignments are executed left-to-right so that `i = arr[i] = f()`
>   evaluates the expression `f()`, then assigns the result to the leftmost
>   target, `i`, and then assigns the same result to the next target,
>   `arr[i]`, using the new value of `i`.

Another [blog post](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/lambda_tutorial/#footnote2) says:

> In Python, assignment statements do not return a value. Chained
>   assignment (or more precisely, code that looks like chained assignment
>   statements) is recognized and supported as a special case of the
>   assignment statement.

This seems the most correct to me, on a closer reading of [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) - in particular  `(target_list "=")+` - which also say

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list ... and assigns
>   the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to
>   right.

So it's not really "evaluated from right-most to left" - the RHS is evaluated and then assigned from left-most target to right - not that I can think of any real-world (or even contrived) examples where it would make a difference.

Comment: my description is from the developers point of view, as you state yourself: there is no *real-world* scenario where the wording would result in different results.

Or well, now I can actually think of one.. hold on, will update my answer with a little snippet to explain what I mean.

Comment: nevermind, it won't make sense (and can't be done without a massive python hack, which is beyond the scope of the question), though I'll update my answer with some information from your post.

Comment: please remember that this isn't like a normal forum where you can reply to previous posts with a new answer, if you have comments regarding contents in one post please use the "comment"-feature, quoting another answer in your post might cause trouble if one post is later deleted/altered.

Comment: @refp I know how to use Stack Overflow. I wasn't replying to your answer, it prompted me to do some more digging and find my own answer. Last time I checked that was the right way to do things - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: since you quoted *"evaluated from right-most to left"* it seemed like a reply, answering your own question is of course fine.

Comment: Contrived example to show order can matter: `x = [0, 1, 2, 3]; x[0:2] = x[1:3] = [4];` results in `[4, 4]`, if you reverse them then it results in `[4, 3]`.

Answer (score 4):

got bitten by python's Chained Assignment today, due to my ignorance. in code

```
if l1.val <= l2.val:
    tail = tail.next = l1 # this line 
    l1 = l1.next
```

what I expected was

```
tail.next = l1
tail = tail.next
# or equivalently 
# tail = l1
```

whereas I got below, which produce a self loop in the list, leave me in a endless loop, whoops...

```
tail = l1
tail.next = l1 # now l1.next is changed to l1 itself
```

since for a = b = c,
one way (python, for example) equivalent to

```
tmp = evaluate(c)
evaluate(a) = tmp
evaluate(b) = tmp
```

and have equal right operand for two assignment.

the other (C++, for example) equivalent to

```
evaluate(b) = evaluate(c)
evaluate(a) = evaluate(b)
```

since in this case `a = b = c` is basically

```
b = c
a = b
```

and two right hand operand could be different.

That why similar code works well in C++.

Comment: Same! I think relying on this ordering is not pythonic however (I was interested in being "tricky" rather than sure it would work), any reader is not going to be 100% which way this goes. Better to be explicit in a case like this.

Comment: The pythonic way to do this would be to use tuple assignment/unpack (if I read your expected code correctly): `tail, tail.next = tail.next, l1`.  The RHS gets fully evaluated, and then assigned left-to-right into the LHS tuple.