# Status of chained assignment in Python

Tags: python

At several occasions I stumbled upon C-style assignment in Python such as `a = b = 0`. By diligent Googling I found out that this is called chained assignment: [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Chained_assignment)],[[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498441/what-is-this-kind-of-assignment-in-python-called-a-b-true)],[[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601823/how-do-chained-assignments-work)]. However, it appears that this feature is not mentioned in the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Does this mean that chained assignment is still in experimental phase, or simply that the official documentation is slightly behind the development?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the official documentation does mention it?

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression)
                                      ^ here
```

Comment: @ssegvic: as well as the narrative text below it: *and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.*

Comment: `from left to right` is important! Notice that `ys=[None]; zs=[True]; xs=ys; xs=xs[0]=zs` has the effect of first doing `xs=zs` then making `xs` be a circular list whose first element is itself. The parallel syntax in C would instead do `xs[0]=zs`, and then rebind `xs` to `zs`. To achieve the C behavior in Python, you'd have to instead do `xs[0] = xs = zs`. The parallel syntax to *that* in C would fail. This can trip one up if converting between C and Python!

Answer (score 0):

You can use chain assignment, but it is not Pythonic style.

From the The Zen of Python;;
"Flat is better than nested. "

Comment: This doesn't seem like an accurate application of this motto to me.

Comment: There is another motto from python family for you Ned, we're all consenting adults here :)