# how does python assignment(=) operator work

Tags: python

I write a linked list，when I use multiple assignment ,the result is strange。What's the different between python and javascript?

The sample python code

```py
class ListNode(object):
def __init__(self, x):
    self.val = x
    self.next = None

node=ListNode(0)
node=node.next=ListNode(10)
#expect node.next=ListNode(10) node=node.next
print(node ==node.next) # True why?
```

The same logic JavaScript code

```
function ListNode(val){
    this.val=val;
    this.next=null;
}
var node=new ListNode(0);
node=node.next=new ListNode(10)
console.log(node==node.next) //false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, evaluation is in reverse order. Therefore this:

```
node = node.next = ListNode(10)
```

is the same as this:

```
node = ListNode(10)
node.next = node
```

So, you have to reverse order of elements before last assignment:

```
node.next = node = ListNode(10)
# same as:
node.next = ListNode(10)
node = node.next
```

Comment: The assignment `node.next = node = ListNode(10)` is the equivalent of `tmp = ListNode(10); node.next = tmp; node = tmp`, with the tmp variable hidden. The answer as written suggests that `node` isn't changed by the assignment, which isn't correct.

Comment: @Craig Thanks. Fixed. :)

Comment: @Craig  where can I know the assignment detail,I can't find in the Python Tutorial

Comment: @shenli - It's in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) _An assignment statement evaluates the expression list ... and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, **from left to right**_ (emphasis mine). I would avoid using this construction for anything other than simple initialization. You see how much confusion it can cause. H/T: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056146/status-of-chained-assignment-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're reassigning `node` to be equal to `node.next`, so `node == node.next` will always be `True` because those two variables are pointing at the same object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the line:

```
node = node.next = ListNode(10)
```

If you just do:

```
node.next = ListNode(10)
```

You will get the result you want

```
in [1]: node=ListNode(0)

In [2]: node.val
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: node.next = ListNode(10)

In [4]: node.val
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: node.next.val
Out[5]: 10

In [6]: node == node.next
Out[6]: False
```

Answer (score -1):

The assignment operation is evaluated from right to left:

```
node.next = ListNode(10)
node = node.next
```

Comment: This is no what's happening!