# Issue with Python implementation of assignment chaining

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a linked list for an educational Python library. Here are the important snippets of code:

```
class Element(object):
  def __init__(self, value, next):
    self.value = value
    self.next = next

class LinkedList(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.tail = None

  def insert_back(self, element):
    if self.empty():
      self.insert_front(element)
    else:
      self.tail.next = Element(element, None)
      self.tail = self.tail.next
      # I'd like to replace the above two lines with this
      # self.tail = self.tail.next = Element(element, None)
```

My issue comes from the last line. According to [the top answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498441/what-is-this-kind-of-assignment-in-python-called-a-b-true), Python's unique implementation of chained assignment is the culprit.

In other languages, the last line would have the same effect as the two lines above it, but Python evaluates the expression `Element(element, None)` first and then assigns the result from left-to-right, so `self.tail` is assigned before `self.tail.next`. This results in the previous tail element not referencing the new tail element, and the new tail element referencing itself.

My question is: is there a way to perform these two assignments with a single statement?

I'm perfectly content using the more explicit two-line assignment; this is just for curiosity's sake.

Comment: >>> a = b = 1
>>> a
1
>>> b
1

Comment: Comments don't like newlines apparently but in your case self.tail = self.tail.next = Element(element, None) would go right to left

Comment: Are you saying `x=1`, `y=2`, `x=y=3` results in `x=2`, `y=3` in python? Because that's not the case. It behaves pretty much like C.

Comment: The issue is because I'm modifying the same reference. In most situations, you're both right, it behaves like C. This issue only shows up because I'm assigning an attribute of a reference and reassigning the reference itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment is *never* chained.

Assignment first evaluates the right-hand expression, *then* assigns the result to the left-hand targets, one by one, from left to right.

See the [assigment statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

So your code:

```
self.tail = self.tail.next = Element(element, None)
```

effectively means:

```
result = Element(element, None)
self.tail = result
self.tail.next = result
```

You could use this instead, simply reversing the assignment order:

```
self.tail.next = self.tail = Element(element, None)
```

which assigns in the correct order:

```
result = Element(element, None)
self.tail.next = result
self.tail = result
```

This results in the correct behaviour for a linked list:

```
>>> head = tail = Element(0, None)
>>> tail.next = tail = Element(1, None)
>>> head.value
0
>>> head.next
<__main__.Element object at 0x10262e510>
>>> head.next.value
1
>>> tail is head.next
True
>>> tail.next = tail = Element(2, None)
>>> tail is head.next.next
True
```

Comment: That's what I gathered from the link in the OP. I'm wondering if there is a way (not necessarily with chained assignments) to do it in one line. I don't believe the multiple assignment solution would work, either, as self.tail would end up as None (self.tail is the tail element, so self.tail.next will _always_ be None).

Comment: @skirkpatrick: actually, just reversing the assignments is enough.

Comment: Wow, I totally thought of this, but my brain said "that won't work!" Thank you for having such a thorough, well explained answer!