# Django's session-based model - id value in settings.py?

Tags: python, django

I am learning to build a product cart app for an online shop. 
But while I was reading other's app, I found something I couldn't understand.

```
settings.py>
CART_ID = 'cart_in_session'


cart.py>
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from shop.models import Product

from coupon.models import Coupon

class Kart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        kart = self.session.get(settings.CART_ID)
        if not kart:
            kart = self.session[settings.CART_ID] = {}
        self.kart = kart
```

I couldn't get this part of code snippet:
if not kart:
     kart = self.session[settings.CART_ID] = {}

It has two "=" symbol and I am wondering if it's for assignment and if it's really an assignment, then why it sets CART_ID's value ("cart_in_session" for its matched key CART_ID) to {}

Comment: This isn't very good code. It would be much better to do `kart = self.session.setdefault(settings.CART_ID, {})`

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Thank you for your help! I never knew the setdefault method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement both creates a new `kart` and creates the session key for the cart, setting both to an empty cart `{}`.

- You can assign multiple variable to the same value by chaining `=` in python. It's the same as these three lines:

  ```
  temp = {}
  kart = temp    
  self.session[settings.CART_ID] = temp
  ```

  Thus assigning both `kart` and the session variable to the same empty dictionary.
- `CART_ID` is a strangely chosen name. It's basically the key that's used to store the card in the session. I would have named it `CART_KEY`. All this code does is initialising an empty cart and adding it to the session.

Note: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11498454/1252711) for more on chained assignment in Python.

Note2: Since we're assigning a dictionary, both `kart` and `session[CART_ID]` point to the same dictionary in memory. If you change `kart` by adding a product, it will automatically be reflected in the session and vice-versa.

Note3: @DanielRoseman's code makes this much more clear.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. So this code isn't efficient in terms of memory management since it assigns two separate things to the same dictionary?