# How does this chain assignment work?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Consider the following code; it is a bad programming practice. I am wondering why the resulting list `A` is `[1, 1, 3]` rather than `[1, 2, 1]`.
From the view of Java, the result should be `[1, 2, 1]`.  Can anyone explain why this result is what it is?

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
t = 2
t = A[t] = A.count(3)
```

After evaluation, A is `[1, 1, 3]` and t is `1`.

My Python version is 3.3.

Comment: you can copy & paste the code in the question, instead of screen capture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On line 3 you have a *chained assignment*

```
t = A[t] = A.count(3)
```

`t = A.count(3)` is evaluated first – `t` set to the return value of `A.count(3)` which in this case is 1.
Then the member of `A` at index `t`(=1) is set to the return value of `A.count(3)`, which is still 1.

Read more about chained assignments in Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601823/how-do-chained-assignments-work)

Answer (score 3):

`A.count(3)` yields `1`.

`t = 1` is executed first. Now `t` is `1`.

`A[t] = 1` is executed. (`A[1] = 1`)

---

```
>>> class Demo:
...     def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
...         print 'Set index', idx
... 
>>> d = Demo()
>>> d[1] = d[2] = 2
Set index 1
Set index 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Haha... The python evaluation of such expression in not as obvious as you may expect from the `t = A[t] = A.count(3)` expression. In first step the value at the end is evaluated with is `1`. Then it is first assigned to `t` and then to `A[t]`, but at this time `t` is 1.

Suggestion by @Henrik to read about *chained assignments* is very good.

Actually, your example self-explain why it is perceived as *bad programming practice*.