# Order of Multiple Assignment

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out what gets assigned to what first? In the following line of code

```
self.tail.next = self.tail = Queue.Node(val)
```

What is the order of assignment? What would be an equivalent in more than one line?

Comment: Is order important, or are you just curious? I want to say right to left, because it doesn't make sense the other way

Comment: For this line to work, order is important.

Comment: [BobStein-VisiBone's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36346517/68587) in the duplicate question is particularly helpful.