# How to correctly assign local variables to a for-loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, local-variables

I am having a `for`-loop which takes rows within a pandas dataframe `df_drinks` and uses them as parameters to call another function `order()`. `order()` is imported from the module `restaurant.py`.

Together with the row in `df_drinks`, I want to submit a `comment` to the `order()`, which is specified outside the for-loop.

```
from restaurant import order

statement = "Lets order"
df_drinks = ["1 drink", "2 drink"] # simplified, 1 item per row, many columns

for index, row in df_drinks.iterrows():
    print ("%s, %s" % (statement, row))
    item = row
    response = order(statement, item)
    ...
```

The module looks like this:

```
# restaurant.py

def order(statement, item):
    listen(statement)
    statement = "order received"
    ready_drinks = prepare(item)
    ...
    return ready_drinks
```

For the first run/row everything is fine since a `print` yields:

**Lets order 1 drink**

However, for the second run/row,  `print` yields:

**order received 2 drinks** instead of **Lets order 2 drinks**.

I understand that I have the same variable name `statement` for two different things. Still, I am confused since `order()` in `restaurant.py` does only return `ready_drinks` and not `statement`.

**How to correctly assign local variables to a for-loop in python?**

Comment: Without more details hard to help. What you have shown cannot change `statement` in the for-loop.

Comment: Are you trying to have `order` assign to the caller's `statement` variable? Python doesn't work that way. It may help to read a [quick explanation of how Python variables actually work](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

statement = "order received" is a local variable and statement = "Lets order" is a Global variable. You are no where overriding the value in the for loop. May be below code helps you

df_drinks = ["1 drink", "2 drink"] # simplified, 1 item per row, many columns

```
for row in df_drinks:
    statement = "Lets order"
    print ("%s, %s" % (statement, row))
    item = row
    ready_drinks,statement = order(statement, item)
    print ("%s, %s" % (statement, row))


def order(statement, item):
    listen(statement)
    statement = "order received"
    ready_drinks = prepare(item)
    ...
    return ready_drinks,statement
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to ask but it appears this might be due to indentation if I am understanding correctly what you are saying so the code becomes.

```
from restaurant import order

statement = "Lets order"
df_drinks = ["1 drink", "2 drink"] # simplified, 1 item per row, many columns

for index, row in df_drinks.iterrows():
    print ("%s, %s" % (statement, row))
    item = row
response = order(statement, item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the answers. I over-simplified. What should have been mentioned initially is that `statement` is not a string in the original code, but a pandas `df`. According to my understanding, this led to issues regarding [Pandas: Chained assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments)
.

The `statement` dataframe undergoes several `inplace = True` processing steps in `restaurants.py` after the first row in the `for` loop of the first code. This led to the above-mentioned changes in all other rows of the `for` loop.

In case someone else may face a similar problem in the future, I want to add how to prevent this: Creating one seperate copy of the dataframe for the group of operations in `restaurants.py`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601823/how-do-chained-assignments-work).

```
statement2 = statement.copy(deep=False)
```