# Why does chained assignment work this way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I found the assignment `a = a[1:] = [2]` in an article.  I tried it in python3 and python2; it all works, but I don't understand *how* it works.  `=` here is not like in C; C processes `=` by right to left.  How does python process the `=` operator?

Comment: I reopened this question because it is a much more complex case than the typical `x = y = some_func()` case addressed in [How do chained assignments work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7601823/364696)

Comment: It can be left to right because assignment is a type of statement in Python and not an expression like in C. It doesn’t have an associativity since `a = b = … = x` is all parsed together.

Comment: The question is only related to the non-complex part though (left-to-right). OP states they understand how it works. I am not strongly against reopening though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per [the language docs on assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

In this case, `a = a[1:] = [2]` has an expression list `[2]`, and two "target lists", `a` and `a[1:]`, where `a` is the left-most "target list".

You can see how this behaves by looking at the disassembly:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('a = a[1:] = [2]')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              2 BUILD_LIST               1
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              8 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             14 BUILD_SLICE              2
             16 STORE_SUBSCR
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

(The last two lines of the disassembly can be ignored, `dis` is making a function wrapper to disassemble the string)

The important part to note is that when you do `x = y = some_val`, `some_val` is loaded on the stack (in this case by the `LOAD_CONST` and `BUILD_LIST`), then the stack entry is duplicated and assigned, from left to right, to the targets given.

So when you do:

```
a = a[1:] = [2]
```

it makes two references to a brand new `list` containing `2`, and the first action is a `STORE` one of these references to `a`. Next, it stores the second reference to `a[1:]`, but since the slice assignment mutates `a` itself, it has to load `a` again, which gets the `list` just stored. Luckily, `list` is resilient against self-slice-assignment, or we'd have issues (it would be forever reading the value it just added to add to the end until we ran out of memory and crashed); as is, it behaves as a copy of `[2]` was assigned to replace any and all elements from index one onwards.

The end result is equivalent to if you'd done:

```
_ = [2]
a = _
a[1:] = _
```

but it avoids the use of the `_` name.

To be clear, the disassembly annotated:

Make list `[2]`:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              2 BUILD_LIST               1
```

Make a copy of the reference to `[2]`:

```
              4 DUP_TOP
```

Perform store to `a`:

```
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
```

Perform store to `a[1:]`:

```
              8 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             14 BUILD_SLICE              2
             16 STORE_SUBSCR
```

Answer (score 7):

The way I understand such assignments is that this is equivalent to

```
temp = [2]
a = temp
a[1:] = temp
```

The resulting value of `[2, 2]` is consistent with this interpretation.