# Multiple slicing assignement with Python

Tags: python-3.x, slice

I was reading a post called "Duplicate each member in a list". I found an answer to solve this problem that I can't understand :

```
>>> a = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5]
>>> a[:0] = a[::2] = a[1::2] = a[:]
>>> a
[3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 5, 5]
```

Could you explain me step by step how works the following line of program :

```
>>> a[:0] = a[::2] = a[1::2] = a[:]
```

Comment: I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633951/why-does-chained-assignment-work-this-way) might solve your doubt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is understanding that the sequence **is executed left-to-right, all with reference to the rightmost value.**

The rightmost slice `a[:]` gets assigned to each of the 3 leftmost slices. Note the use of `a[:]` instead of `a`, this ensures we make *one copy at the beginning* and our operations on `a` don't change this value. A clearer way to write this would be to store the copy `a[:]`:

```py
>>> a = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b
[3, 1, 4, 1, 5]

>>> a[:0] = b
>>> a
[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5]
#^^^^^^^^^^^^^ changed

>>> a[::2] = b
>>> a
[3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 5, 5]
#^     ^     ^     ^     ^ changed 

>>> a[1::2] = b
>>> a
[3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 5, 5]
#   ^     ^     ^     ^     ^ changed
```

Let us discuss the individual steps

1. `b = a[:]` makes a temp copy of a
2. `a[:0] = b` inserts `b` at the front, but is actually just used for padding a to twice the length, so that the next two statements work
3. `a[::2] = b` sets the values at even indices (i.e. every second index starting from the front)
4. `a[1::2] = b` sets the values at odd indices (i.e. every second index excluding the front)

---

Another way to get the same result is the following tuple assignment, which also evaluates the right-hand-side first, and then the left-hand-side from left-to-right:

```
(a[:0], a[::2], a[1::2]) = (a[:], a[:], a[:])
```