# How can I view Python objects created in a RMardown session in RStudio Environment window?

Tags: python, r, rstudio, r-markdown, reticulate

I have created a RMarkdown document with some objects in a Python code chunk. I'd like to be able to see these objects in the Environment window list in RStudio like the objects created in a R code chunk.

For instance, if I create a vetor, say:

```
a = c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

in a R code chunk (i.e. if I wrap the code with `{r}`, it will appear in the Environment window list.

On the other hand, if I create another vector in a Python code chunk, like the one below:

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

b will not be listed in the Environment window. At least, I was not able to find a way to have it shown there.

On the other hand, b can be accessed in a R code chunk by prefixing it with "py$" like "py$b"

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any chunk that assigns to a Python variable `b`, follow that assignment with a command like `r.b = b`.  Then `b` and its value will appear in the Environment window.

`r.` is the converse of `py$`; it lets the Python chunk access the R namespace.

Reference:  https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/03/26/reticulate-r-interface-to-python/

---

**Edit**:  to be more concise, you could chain the assignment:
`r.b = b = [1,2,3,4,5]`

Not completely sure it's wise, though.  The whole thing about Python chain assignments going left-to-right (see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/36346517) freaks me out.  The point made there about two Python variables pointing to the same object should be kept in mind, although as far as I can tell, assigning a new value to `b` in an R chunk doesn't change the value of `py$b`.