# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment pandas add column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new with pandas...I'm trying add a new colum to a df (df['new_col']) ..but when I make have this error:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

res = requests.get("http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken")
j = res.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(j['result'])
#add column
df = df['new_col'] = '12'
print(df.head())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas_csv.py", line 8, in <module>
    df = df['new_col'] = '12'
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to explain why that's happening, here's a simpler MCVE of the problem:

```
d = {1: "a"}
d = d[1] = "3"

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

This happens because, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36346517/3000206), `df = df['new_col'] = '12'` is equivilent to:

```
df = "3"
df['new_col'] = '12'
```

Now, it should be obvious why the error is happening. `df` is overwritten with a string before the `'new_col'` assignment happens.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace

```
df = df['new_col'] = '12'
```

by

```
df['new_col'] = '12'
```