# Details about how a=b=c works

Tags: python, variable-assignment, equality

From this answer: [How do chained assignments work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601823/how-do-chained-assignments-work/36346517#36346517), I understand that chained assignement in Python :

```
x = y = z      # (1)
```

is equivalent to:

```
temp = z
x = temp
y = temp
```

But is (1) also equivalent to:

```
x = z
y = x
```

?

Or is there a slight difference (for example when `z = some_function()`)? If so, which difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the very example you give, yes, the effects of the two approaches are practically identical because both involve simply assigning the same reference to a number of names.

Be aware, however, that if the expressions in the assignment targets involve more complex evaluations, the two approaches could be different.

For example, consider the following chain expression, where `x` is initialized as a dict and `expensive_func` is a time-consuming function that returns a key:

```
x[expensive_func()] = y = some_function()
```

While it would be indeed equivalent to the following:

```
temp = some_function()
x[expensive_func()] = temp
y = temp
```

it would not be be equivalent to the second approach:

```
x[expensive_func()] = some_function()
y = x[expensive_func()]
```

since `expensive_func` would then have to be called twice, doubling the time taken, and triggering the side effect of the function twice, if it has any.

Also, consider the following code:

```
obj = []
x = []
x[:] = y = obj
print(id(obj), id(x), id(y))
```

where the output would show that `y` gets assigned the same reference as `obj`, while `x` is different.

That code is then indeed equivalent to:

```
obj = []
x = []
temp = obj
x[:] = temp
y = temp
print(id(obj), id(x), id(y))
```

But not equivalent to:

```
obj = []
x = []
x[:] = obj
y = x[:]
print(id(obj), id(x), id(y))
```

The latter of which would show `y` getting a different reference from both `obj` and `x`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make the conclusion clearer then.

Comment: why is it not identical, your case tests one scenario?

Comment: Oops I indeed misunderstood the question and thought it was asking about "Are x = y = z and y = x = z equivalent?" I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: Thank you for these examples, with `id`, very insightful.

Comment: I also discovered that each time we call `x[:]`, it generates a *new* copy, is that right? `x = []; y = x[:]; z = x[:]; print(id(x), id(y), id(z))` : 3 different references!

Comment: That's right. Slicing a list creates a new copy unless the slicing is done in an assignment target, in which case the assignment replaces the values of the slice in-place, which is what would happen in `x[:] = z`.

Answer (score 1):

I always find using examples to be the best way to understand things (in general).

Let's say we have a func:

```
def function_sample ():
  print(20)
```

If you print it:

```
print(function_sample)

<function function_sample at 0x7f8f840a01f0>
```

returns the function object.

When assigning to a variable a function without parentheses (without calling/running it).

```
x = function_sample
print(x)
```

you will get the same message:     `<function function_sample at 0x7f8f840a01f0>`

However, if you run it (with parentheses).

```
print(x())
```

You will see :

```
20
None
```

Why None? It's because Python functions have a default return value, which is None if no return expression is given, or return is given on its own.

Another sample:

```
def another_sample(some):
  print(some)

y = another_sample
print(y)
```

As you probably have guessed it `: <function another_sample at 0x7f8f7e747700>`

If you try to print y() you will get an error because the `some` argument is missing.

But if we add one:

```
print(y(5))

5
None
```

One last example:

```
def third_sample ():
  return 20

aa = third_sample    # without running the func
bb = third_sample()  # calling/running the func

print(aa) # function object
print(bb) # 20
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, but the question is not "What is the difference between x and x()?"  ;)

Answer (score 0):

The 2 approaches you have shown are both functional and legit in terms of going about chaining and using previous variables. No difference at all

When assigning variables to the same number of variables, instead of doing the typical:

```
x = 0
y = 0
```

OR using tuple unpacking approach:

```
(x,y) = 0,0
```

You could just do like what you have (chained assignment):

```
x = y = 0
```

This could be used with any object (being called on) for the RHS, and that:

```
x = y = some_object()
```

is the same as:

```
tmp = some_object()
x = tmp
y = tmp
```

and when you `del tmp`, the `x`and `y` become useless or nothing.

Comment: Your post is interesting but does not really answer the question: what is the difference between the two solutions mentioned in the question? Is it identical or not?

Comment: Yup, they are identical, the way you have it seems right, it's always a good idea to do some debugging on ide to reassure your cases are right.

Comment: I know that `x=y=z` <=> `tmp=z; x=tmp; y=tmp`. The question here is: is it also strictly equivalent to `x=z; y=z`?