# Iterating through a linked list with chain assignments

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, linked-list

Let's say I have the following names and objects

```
original = n = <original_object>
n = n.next = <new_object>
```

After running the above I would expect to see `original` pointing to `<original_object>`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

However, if I instead do:

```
original = n = <original_object>
n.next = <new_object> # Attribute of the object class
n = n.next
```

I then see `original` pointing to `<original_object>` (or at least that's what I think I see).

### Concrete example

I'll illustrate this with a linked list in Python 3.8:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.next = None
```

With chain assignments:

```
head = n = Node(None)
n = n.next = Node(None)
print(head.next) # None (the "head" is gone?)
```

With consecutive assignments:

```
head = n = Node(None) 
n.next = Node(None) # *
n = n.next # *
print(head.next) # <__main__.Node object at 0x7fa4e0610ca0>
```

My intention here is to preserve the "head" of the linked list as I add nodes at the tail. Why am I getting different results with chain vs consecutive assignments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do chained assignments work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601823/how-do-chained-assignments-work)

Comment: You're assigning `n` and `n.next` to the same `Node()`, and after `n = Node()` has run. That means `head` isn't affected because `n` was reassigned first before `n.next = Node()` ran. See the top non-accepted answer.

Comment: Excellent. It does. Thanks @Carcigenicate. Good to close then. Sorry I missed that :/

Comment: This is certainly an oddity of Python that bites everyone eventually, like mutable default arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@Carcigenicate** quickly noted, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36346517/283296) explains what's happening:

In short, following that argument in my example, If I do:

```
n = n.next = Node(None)
```

that's equivalent to:

```
temp = Node(None)
n = temp
n.next = temp
```

so `n` gets assigned a *new* node **before** I "advance the current pointer" (`n`) in the linked list, whereas what I want to do is create a *new* node first, link to it, and *then* "advance the current pointer" (`n`) to the new node.