# What is the problem with this chained assignment?

Tags: python, linked-list

I was doing the following LeetCode exercise

```
class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
         self.val = val
         self.next = next

class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        if l1 and l2:
            if l1.val < l2.val:
                temp = head = ListNode(l1.val)
                l1 = l1.next
            else:
                temp = head = ListNode(l2.val)
                l2 = l2.next
            while l1 and l2:
                if l1.val < l2.val:
                    temp = temp.next = ListNode(l1.val)
                    #temp.next = temp = ListNode(l1.val)
                    l1 = l1.next
                else:
                    temp = temp.next = ListNode(l2.val)
                    #temp.next = temp = ListNode(l2.val)
                    l2 = l2.next
       ...
```

My question is why the lines `temp = temp.next = ListNode(l1.val)` and `temp = temp.next = ListNode(l2.val)` don't work and the commented lines right below them do?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"?

Comment: I don't get any error messages.

Comment: @AlanLiddell don't work = in the end the list only has one element

Comment: @vmp You should edit your question to make this clear. What is the expected behavior, what is the actual behavior?

Comment: @AlanLiddell I didn't want to paste the whole code because the question was basically what happens when I change the order of the assignment.

Comment: @vmp the point was actually to *reduce* the code to the essential part, not add more unnecessary parts.

Comment: @mapf I tried doing that... That's why I've put the `...` at the end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do chained assignments work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601823/how-do-chained-assignments-work) See the second answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They mean fundamentally different things:

```py
temp = temp.next = ListNode(l1.val)
```

is equivalent to:

```py
_node = ListNode(l1.val)
temp = _node
temp.next = _node
```

Whereas

```py
temp.next = temp = ListNode(l1.val)
```

is equivalent to:

```py
_node = ListNode(l1.val)
temp.next = _node
temp = _node
```

The second one assigns the `next` property of the current `temp` node to a new node, then sets `temp` to be the new node, which is the correct behavior. The first sets `temp` to the new node, then sets its `next` property to be itself, which is incorrect.

Comment: So the assignments are done from left to right in python?

Comment: @vmp Yes they are.

Comment: Why is the second version the correct one? What is the point of assigning a value to attribute of an object only to immediatly overwrite the identifier?

Comment: @mapf Because it's a linked list, so `temp` is already stored in the `next` attribute of the previous node, so mutating `temp` then reassigning it does actually have an effect.

Comment: @Aplet123 Oh that makes sense.. the syntax looks counter-intuitive to me, but I think I see it now. Thanks!