# Why does the order matter in this chained assignment?

Tags: python, chained-assignment

As shown by the following two code snippets, the order of the chained assignment matters (i.e. `node = node[ch] = {}` is not equivalent to `node[ch] = node = {}`.

```
trie = {}
node = trie
for ch in "word":
    if ch in node:
        node = node[ch]
    else:
        node = node[ch] = {} # chained assignment #1
print(trie) # {}
```

```
trie = {}
node = trie
for ch in "word":
    if ch in node:
        node = node[ch]
    else:
        node[ch] = node = {} # chained assignment #2
print(trie) # {'w': {'o': {'r': {'d': {}}}}}
```

Why does the order matter?

---

According to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601823/how-do-chained-assignments-work), the chained assignment

```
a = b = c
```

is equivalent to:

```
tmp = c
a = c
b = c
```

and I verified that the equivalent forms produced the same behavior. I.e.

```
        # node = node[ch] = {} # chained assignment #1
        tmp = {}
        node = tmp
        node[ch] = tmp
```

leads to a `print(trie)` of `{}`.

Meanwhile

```
        node[ch] = node = {} # chained assignment #2
        tmp = {}
        node[ch] = tmp
        node = tmp
```

leads to a `print(trie)` of `{'w': {'o': {'r': {'d': {}}}}}`.

Comment: Backing up from your "why" question, what's the behavior you _want_?

Comment: In particular, do you want `node` and `node[ch]` to point to the same dict instance, or do you want them each to have a separate dict? When you have `a = b = {}`, there's only one new dict created.

Comment: I suspect that using `defaultdict` may make a lot of sense in your use case, insofar as your goal is being able to tersely define nested dictionaries.

Comment: `def dict_of_dicts(): return collections.defaultdict(dict_of_dicts)` means that if you specify `trie = dict_of_dicts()`, you can then run `trie['a']['b']['c'] = {}` without previously initializing `trie['a']` or `trie['a']['b']`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks! I wanted the behavior of the second chained assignment. (Sorry for the delay in replying.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically answered your question at the end.

```
node = tmp
node[ch] = tmp
```

and

```
node[ch] = tmp
node = tmp
```

are not equivalent. As soon as you do `node = tmp`, you lose the previous contents of `node`, and replace them with a new dict. That means that in the first case, you immediately lose the reference to `trie` inside the loop, and can no longer mutate it. In the second case, you *alter the old results*, then reassign `node` to the new dictionary.