# How does assignment to another assignment(adding an element in a dictionary) work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment

Let's imagine a dictionary and we want to get some kind of a "reference" to a value that hasn't been populated yet.

```
>>> d = {} # This dictionary may have a huge number of elements.
>>> a = d['John'] = {} # I hope 'a' works as if some reference to the empty value.
>>> d
{'John': {}}
>>> a['age'] = 20
>>> d
{'John': {'age': 20}} # worked as hoped, but how did the 2nd line above work?
```

In the 2nd line in the above example, I wanted the `a` to work as a reference to the empty value, and it worked as I hoped. But how exactly does `a = d['John'] = {}` work?

It would make some sense if it were equivalent to `a = (d['John'] = {})` and if assignment were an expression. But in Python, assignment is not an expression as far as I know. Maybe `myDict['someKey'] = 'someValue'` is not a typical assignment in Python?

Could somebody explain how the 2nd line works?

Comment: one good way to look at the nuts and bolts of how these work is to use the dissasembler, `dis.dis("a = b = c")`

Comment: Python allows to assign the same value to many variables `x = y = z = 0`

Comment: to future me) 1. Remember that many modern languages(Python, Java, C#, etc.) use the same(as far as I know) assignment method if considering only one assignment(one `=`) - it's just like using a pointer or reference (so it's like copying the memory address of RHS object to LHS, _not_ the RHS object itself), and this is _different_ from that of C/C++ which copy the RHS _itself_ to LHS when using assignment(`=`).

Comment: 2. But if considering multiple assignments (eg`a=b=c`), the aforementioned modern languages(Python, Java, ...) might use different rules (although only one `=` works the same way). When it comes to Python, reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36346517/10027592) and then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59326908/10027592) would be fun and helpful.

Comment: Since Python is a high level language, you need to think about it in high level terms, not C. `a = b = c` assigns `c` to `a` and `b`. `a` and `b` refer to the same object. Just like in `a = c`, `b = c`.

Comment: (...continued from the above comments of mine) 3. Not directly related to the question, but considering the intent of it: The method used in the question(make a "reference" and fill the empty object later) is good, but also consider using _nested_ dictionary/list/both comprehension. E.g. something like `d = { p1["key"]: { p2["key"]: [e for e in p2["value"]] for p2 in p1["value"] } for p1 in m }`