# why does final_dictionary = starting_dictionary["c"] = 7 not assign starting_list with added key-value pair to final_dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, assign, assignment-operator

**How are these two different.
**
(1)

```
starting_dictionary = {
    "a": 9,
    "b": 8,
}
final_dictionary = {
    "a": 9,
    "b": 8,
    "c": 7,
}
final_dictionary = starting_dictionary["c"] = 7
print(starting_dictionary)
print(final_dictionary)
```

(2)

```
starting_dictionary = {
    "a": 9,
    "b": 8,
}
final_dictionary = {
    "a": 9,
    "b": 8,
    "c": 7,
}
starting_dictionary["c"] = 7
final_dictionary = starting_dictionary
print(starting_dictionary)
print(final_dictionary)
```

My main doubt is regarding the (1) code snippet, why does it not work like this :
*starting_dictionary should add a new key-value pair of "c":7
*starting_dictionary should be assigned to final_dictionary
*And now final_dictionary should have all of starting_dictionary with added key-value pair

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do chained assignments work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601823/how-do-chained-assignments-work) Tl;dr writing `final_dictionary = starting_dictionary["c"] = 7` is like writing `final_dictionary = 7` and `starting_dictionary["c"] = 7`

Comment: Simply put, evaluation order is from left to right.

Comment: If you really want to do this in a one-liner, you can use an assignment expression (aka "walrus operator"). `(final_dictionary := starting_dictionary)["c"] = 7` - this does what you were expecting (1) to do.

Answer (score 0):

In code snippet (1), the issue lies in the line:

```
final_dictionary = starting_dictionary["c"] = 7
```

This line of code doesn't achieve what you're intending. It actually assigns the value 7 to the key "c" in the starting_dictionary and then assigns the same value 7 to final_dictionary. It does not create a new dictionary with the added key-value pair.

Because:

starting_dictionary["c"] = 7: This modifies the starting_dictionary by adding the key "c" with the value 7.

final_dictionary = starting_dictionary["c"] = 7: It is equivalent to the below two steps-

starting_dictionary["c"] = 7: Modifies starting_dictionary.
final_dictionary = 7: Assigns the value 7 to final_dictionary.
So, after executing this line, both starting_dictionary and final_dictionary are pointing to the value 7, not to dictionaries.

On the other hand, code snippet (2)
correctly adds the key-value pair to starting_dictionary and then assigns the reference of starting_dictionary to final_dictionary. Therefore, both dictionaries will have the same content after the execution of the code in snippet (2).

Comment: Well done for knowing how to use an AI client to get this information

Comment: The order of operations is the reverse of what you say. It's first `final_dictionary=7` and second `starting_dictionary["c"]=7`. It doesn't really make a difference here, but it does in other situations, for example `x=2; y={}; x=y[x]=7`, which does `x=7` followed by `y[x]=7`. The result is that `y` is `{7:7}`, not `{2:7}`.

Comment: *"So, after executing this line, both starting_dictionary and final_dictionary are pointing to the value 7, not to dictionaries."* No, `starting_dictionary` still refers to a dictionary.